# find characters from string and break string and convert to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match

I have following input array.

```
$action_array = Array
(
    0 => 'quote_item_price{}200',
    1 => 'quote_item_qty>=5',
    2 => 'quote_item_row_total=140',
    3 => 'attribute_set_id<=4',
    4 => 'quote_grand_total!{}100'
);
```

What I want:If I run above array in foreach loop string breaks from characters and convert in array of each string. 
I want Output like this:

1.`array(0=>quote_item_price,1=>200) and should return'{}'` 
2.`array(0=>quote_item_qty,1=>5) and should return '>='` 
3.`array(0=>quote_item_row_total,1=>140) and should return '='` 
4.`array(0=>attribute_set_id,1=>4) and should return '<='` 
5.`array(0=>quote_grand_total,1=>100) and should return '!{}'`

I have used follwing code but not work.

```
$action_format = array();
foreach($action_array as $action){

 if( strpos( $action, "=" ) !== false ) {
                $action_break = explode('=',$action);
                $action_format[] = array
                    (
                        'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
                        'attribute' => $action_break[0],
                        'operator' => '=',
                        'value' => $action_break[1]
                    );
            }
else if( strpos( $action, ">=" ) !== false ) {
                $action_break = explode('>=',$action);
                $action_format[] = array
                    (
                        'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
                        'attribute' => $action_break[0],
                        'operator' => '>=',
                        'value' => $action_break[1]
                    );
            }
 else if( strpos( $action, "<=" ) !== false ) {
                $action_break = explode('<=',$action);
                $action_format[] = array
                    (
                        'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
                        'attribute' => $action_break[0],
                        'operator' => '<=',
                        'value' => $action_break[1]
                    );
            }
else if( strpos( $action, "{}" ) !== false ) {
            $action_break = explode('{}',$action);
            $action_format[] = array
                (
                    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
                    'attribute' => $action_break[0],
                    'operator' => "{}",
                    'value' => $action_break[1]
                );
        }
else if( strpos( $action, "!{}" ) !== false ) {
            $action_break = explode('!{}',$action);
            $action_format[] = array
                (
                    'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
                    'attribute' => $action_break[0],
                    'operator' => "!{}",
                    'value' => $action_break[1]
                );
        }
}
print_r($action_format);
```

Please Help me on this task

Comment: Your code works. What is the problem? Just reorder if conditions. Now you first test `=` which includes `>=`

Comment: @splash58 my code works but when string is "quote_item_qty>=5" it goes in first if condition where it match with = character .it does not go into second if condition

Comment: here is working code - https://eval.in/776683 You need to swap conditoins

Comment: I also thought change order of conditions but I am finding convenient way. bytheway thanks @splash58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of repetition.  I would just use a regex:

```
$keys = array('type', 'attribute', 'operator', 'value');

foreach($action_array as $k => $v) {
    preg_match('/(\w+)([^\d]+)([\d]+)/', $v, $matches);
    $action_format[$k] = array_combine($keys, $matches);
    $action_format[$k]['type'] = 'salesrule/rule_condition_product';
}
```

If your data is not clean and predictable you could check the individual matches in the loop and decide whether to add to the array or not.

- `(\w+)` one or more word characters, followed by
- `([^\d]+)` one or more NOT digits, followed by
- `([\d]+)` one or more digits

Based on your comment to another answer:

> but actually intital string like this `quote_item_price{}200^quote_item_qty>=5^quote_item_row_total‌​=140^attribute_set_i‌​d=4` in a cell of csv file so I get this string convert into array by spliting a ^ character then I wrote my problem

One pass will do it starting with that string:

```
$string = "quote_item_price{}200^quote_item_qty>=5^quote_item_row_total‌​=140^attribute_set_i‌​d=4";

preg_match_all('/(\w+)([^\d]+)([\d]+)\^/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$keys = array('type', 'attribute', 'operator', 'value');

foreach($matches as $k => $v) {
    $action_format[$k] = array_combine($keys, $v);
    $action_format[$k]['type'] = 'salesrule/rule_condition_product';
}
```

Comment: NP, I added something

Comment: Oh very very thanks.you are genius.I think you are magician ha ha ha.Once again thank you .You solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this, outputs are as commented:

```
<?php
function oneLine(&$line){
    preg_match("/(.*?)(!{}|{}|>=|<=|=)(.*)/", $line, $matches);
    $line = array($matches[1], $matches[3]);
    return $matches[2];
}

$arr = array(
        'quote_item_price{}200',
        'quote_item_qty>=5',
        'quote_item_row_total=140',
        'attribute_set_id<=4',
        'quote_grand_total!{}100'
    );

/*
print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [0] => quote_item_price{}200
    [1] => quote_item_qty>=5
    [2] => quote_item_row_total=140
    [3] => attribute_set_id<=4
    [4] => quote_grand_total!{}100
)
 */
foreach($arr as &$action){
    // The following line modifies the array element AND returns the separator
    print_r(oneLine($action)); // {} OR >= OR = OR <= OR !{}
}
/*
print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => quote_item_price
            [1] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => quote_item_qty
            [1] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => quote_item_row_total
            [1] => 140
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => attribute_set_id
            [1] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => quote_grand_total
            [1] => 100
        )

)
 */
```

Answer (score -1):

If array elements are themselves arrays, you need to declare them that way. Also, strings need to be quoted.

```
<?php
$action_array = array
(
    0 => 'quote_item_price{}200',
    1 => 'quote_item_qty>=5',
    2 => 'quote_item_row_total=140',
    3 => 'attribute_set_id<=4',
    4 => 'quote_grand_total!{}100'
);

$action_format = array();

echo "<ul>\n";
foreach($action_array as $key => $statement) {
    $reg_ex = '/([a-zA-Z_!]*)([{}=><!]*)([0-9]*)/';
    $matches = array();
    $rslt = preg_match($reg_ex, $statement, $matches);
    $action_format[] = array(
        'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
        'attribute' => $matches[1],
        'operator' => $matches[2],
        'value' => $matches[3]
        );
    echo "<li>(".$rslt.") [".$statement."] ".print_r($matches,true)."</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
echo "<p>\$action_format: <pre>".print_r($action_format,true)."</pre></p>\n";
?>
```

Output from php code above:

```
    (1) [quote_item_price{}200] Array ( [0] => quote_item_price{}200 [1] => quote_item_price [2] => {} [3] => 200 )
    (1) [quote_item_qty>=5] Array ( [0] => quote_item_qty>=5 [1] => quote_item_qty [2] => >= [3] => 5 )
    (1) [quote_item_row_total=140] Array ( [0] => quote_item_row_total=140 [1] => quote_item_row_total [2] => = [3] => 140 )
    (1) [attribute_set_id<=4] Array ( [0] => attribute_set_id<=4 [1] => attribute_set_id [2] => <= [3] => 4 )
    (1) [quote_grand_total!{}100] Array ( [0] => quote_grand_total!{}100 [1] => quote_grand_total! [2] => {} [3] => 100 )

$action_format:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => salesrule/rule_condition_product
            [attribute] => quote_item_price
            [operator] => {}
            [value] => 200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => salesrule/rule_condition_product
            [attribute] => quote_item_qty
            [operator] => >=
            [value] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => salesrule/rule_condition_product
            [attribute] => quote_item_row_total
            [operator] => =
            [value] => 140
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => salesrule/rule_condition_product
            [attribute] => attribute_set_id
            [operator] => <=
            [value] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [type] => salesrule/rule_condition_product
            [attribute] => quote_grand_total!
            [operator] => {}
            [value] => 100
        )

)
```

Comment: but actually intital string like this quote_item_price{}200^quote_item_qty>=5^quote_item_row_total=140^attribute_set_id=4 in a cell of csv file so I get this string convert into array by spliting a ^ character then I wrote my problem

Comment: Don't put code in comments - it's unreadable, and gets mangled by the formatting. Add it to your question

Comment: The first code sample in your question isn't valid syntax. PHP would error out if that were actually in your code.

Comment: I've updated the code to produce the output array you described, and tested it on SQL Fiddle. Should do what you want. I don't understand the downvotes, whoever down voted the answer, please explain why. We all need to learn sometimes.

Comment: Thanks @slon thrasher. I do not downvote .I can upvote for you.thanks